# The last 0 of a decimal can ben visible in the database in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

I just want to know if a decimal can show me the 0 at the end? I'm using the decimal for some money input. So I want to see the 0 at the end. Some peoples say to don't user money type so ...

Se exemple in my image here :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you store `345.5054` be `decimal(19,2)`, the number will be `345.50` and it's number type so will display `345.5`

You can try to store the value be `decimal(19,2)` and use `FORMAT` function.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  v DECIMAL(19,4)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (345.5045)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(v AS DECIMAL(19,2)),2) v1,
       CAST(v AS DECIMAL(19,2)) v2
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/465348/3/0)**:

```
|     v1 |    v2 |
|--------|-------|
| 345.50 | 345.5 |
```

Comment: OK if i correctly understand, the format in de DB will always with no zero at the end? but the 54 at the end was only in test... but the real number are only 345.50. You can see it like money amount

Comment: Yes if your column is a number type and the value contains decimal point values